# Ajax pagination for Instagram API tried to fix bug

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, instagram

I'm trying to fix Ajax pagination for Instagram API

Shown only 20 photos. "Load more" button didn't work.

In console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: maxid is not defined
```

Here is index.php:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#more').click(function() {
 var max_id = $(this).data('nextid');


 $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'ajax.php',
 data: {
 max_id: maxid
 },
 dataType: 'json',
 cache: false,
 success: function(data) {
 // Output data
 $.each(data.images, function(i, src) {
 $('#photos').append('<li><img src="' + src + '"></li>');
 });

 // Store new maxid
 $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);
 }
 });
 });
 });
</script>

<?php


 require_once 'instagram.class.php';


$instagram = new Instagram(array(
  'apiKey' => '*****',
  'apiSecret' => '*****',
  'apiCallback' => '******'

));

// Receive OAuth code parameter
$code = $_GET['code'];

if (true === isset($code)) {

$data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);

$instagram->setAccessToken($data);


$media = $instagram->getUserMedia();


}
?>


<ul id="photos">

<?php foreach( $media->data as $data ): ?>
<li><img src="<?php echo $data->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php echo "<br><button id=\"more\" data-maxid=\"{$media->pagination->next_max_id}\">Load more ...</button>"; ?>
```

ajax.php:

```
require_once 'instagram.class.php';
$instagram = new Instagram(array(
  'apiKey' => '****',
  'apiSecret' => '*****',
  'apiCallback' => '*******'

));

// Receive OAuth code parameter
$code = $_GET['code'];

if (true === isset($code)) {

$data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);

 // Initialize class for public requests
 $instagram->setAccessToken($data);

$media = $instagram->getUserMedia();


 // Receive AJAX request and create call object
 $maxID = $_GET['next_max_id'];

 $clientID = $instagram->getApiKey();

 $call = new stdClass;
 $call->pagination->next_max_id = $maxID;
 $call->pagination->next_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?client_id={$clientID}&max_id={$maxID}";


 // Receive new data
 $media = $instagram->pagination($call);

 // Collect everything for json output
 $images = array();
 foreach ($media->data as $data) {
 $images[] = $data->images->thumbnail->url;
  }
 echo json_encode(array(
 'next_id' => $media->pagination->next_max_id,
'max_id' => $media->pagination->max_id,
 'images' => $images
 ));
```

I am using https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

How can it be clearer than:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: maxid is not defined
```

`maxid` is not defined in your code. What is defined is `max_id` in this line:

```
var max_id = $(this).data('nextid');
```

Comment: **This error when clicking "load more" button in index.php:**
> Uncaught ReferenceError: maxid is not defined

So what I need to put instead of **maxid** ?

There are max_id and next_max_id from responce:

    {
      "pagination":  {
        "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/********/media/recent?access_token=33174964.1fb234f.707411a10e624f13b6b08dd806df1eab&max_id=278169081097328255_33174964",
        "next_max_id": "278169081097328255_33174964"
      },

Answer (score 0):

There are just 2 locations with `maxid`:

Here:

> $.ajax({
>   ...
>   max_id: maxid
>   },

and here:

> // Store new maxid
>   $('#more').data('maxid', data.next_id);

When you replace these occurences with your defined `max_id` (thanks to @mathieu) it should be fixed.

In your `ajax.php` you have a line:

> $maxID = $_GET['next_max_id'];

This doesn't correspond to your call above, where you have a `max_id`. Seems like you mixed some `next/max/id`. If you look through your code and clean up these ids, it should work.

Comment: Can you tell more in detail please what to do? I tried to change max_id from maxid to nextid. What did You mean "When you replace these occurences with your defined max_id..."?

Comment: You have `maxid`, `nextid`, `max_id` and `next_max_id` in those two sources. It's just a guess, but probably these names mean all the same thing. You should know, since this is your code. *If* these are the same, you can just replace all of them with `max_id`. As a rule of thumb: if you use something, give it just one name everywhere, otherwise you or your colleagues will become confused, sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
.data('nextid');
```

is a careless error as that doesn't exist in your DOM.  Unless it's somewhere else and you haven't posted it.

Did you mean to have

```
.data('maxid');
```

?

Comment: Ok that is certainly a problem in your code.  It might just be one of a few or many.  Now log the value of maxid to the console (or use an alert) right after you set it.  If it is undefined then your selector is getting nothing and you need to look at your HTML.  You should post the generated HTML, not the server code that creates it.

Comment: I would also inspect the data coming into your success handler on the ajax call.  That may show your error is on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `event` argument with the click
and get the `data` from  `event.target`.
Change the first lines of codes into this:

```
$('#more').click(function( event ) {
var max_id = $(event.target).data('nextid');
```