# Load more instead of going to next page using pagination/API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination, instagram-api

I am working on a project to display select Instagram photos in an album by hashtag, since the Instagram API limits 35 images per API call I figured out I either had to use AJAX (which I am **very** poor at) or a mixture of PHP and AJAX. I decided on the latter because I didn't want my access token and user ID made available in the code on my gallery.

```
    <?PHP
function jsongram($next=null){
    $userid = "xxx";
    $accessToken = "xxx";
    $url = ("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}");

    if($url !== null) {
        $url .= '&max_id=' . $next;
    }

    //Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
    $cache = './'.sha1($url).'.json';
    //unlink($cache); // Clear the cache file if needed

    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
        // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
    }else{
        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }


   ?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $data_array = array(); 
    foreach ($jsonData->data as $data){
      if (stripos($data->caption->text,'egypt') === false) {
      }
      else{
        $data_array[] = $data;
        $data = (str_split($data->caption->text)); 
        $data = (array_filter($data));  

      }
    }
    foreach ($data_array as $data):{
    $igimglow = $data->images->low_resolution->url;
    $igimgstd = $data->images->standard_resolution->url;
    $igimgthumb = $data->images->thumbnail->url;
    $igcaption = str_replace('#', '', (preg_replace('/(?:#[\w-]+\s*)+$/', '', $data->caption->text)));
    $igtime = date("F j, Y", $data->caption->created_time);
    $iglikes = $data->likes->count;
    $igcomments = $data->comments->count;
    $iglong = $data->location->longitude;
    $iglat = $data->location->latitude ;
    $igusername = $data->user->username;
    $igfullname = $data->user->full_name;
    $iglink = $data->link;
    $igfilter = $data->filter;
    $igtags = implode(',',$data->tags);
    ?>
            <img src="<?php echo ($igimglow);}?>">
            <?php endforeach ?>

<?php

    if(isset($jsonData->pagination->next_max_id)) {
        $result .= '<div><a href="?next=' . $jsonData->pagination->next_max_id . '">Next</a></div>';
    }

    return $result;
}
?>
    <div id="container">
        <?=jsongram(@$_GET['next']);?>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a live example of the above code:

http://johnricedesign.com/examples/pn.php

As shown above on the 2nd page photos tagged with "egypt" are displayed. I would like to replace the "Next" link to automatically load on the same page with a "Load More" button - to the best of my knowledge using AJAX is the only way of doing so. However I do not know how to do so, or even where to start. The second obvious problem I have is that even though I am removing the photos that don't contain the caption of "egypt" I am still getting a lot of blank spaces, I presume that will be rather simple to fix once AJAX is being used.

I have been pulling my hair out for the last 5 days trying to do this. You help, advice, wisdom, are much appreciated in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this??  http://davidwalsh.name/demo/lazyload-2.0.php

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes - No, that loads images up when the page is scrolled, I need the make a new API call to load up 35 more images every time the page is scrolled/a button is clicked. But visually that is very close to what I am trying to do.

Comment: You can customize this api as per your need(i.e. control image number). Check the documentation and it will become clear to you. Let me know.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes - I reviewed the code and documentation. Unless I am missing something there is nowhere in this code that makes an API call to anything, parses uses JSON to get the image URLs, and then dynamically inserts them into a new page. While I would love it to look visually similar to that, that code is completely different than what needs to be done, unless I am missing something.

Comment: You can also view this: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html

Comment: in that link, check the Javascript. There is something like 'items : 4,'. By using that you can control how many images you want to show each scroll.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes - While I appreciate your attempt at helping me, these codes are in no way using API calls, or even communicating with another server. Please look at my demo and my code to understand what I am trying to accomplish. I am fairly certain AJAX needs to be used.

Comment: brother you need to customize the whole ajax thing and integrate it with the last tool i gave you. I already worked with something similar to you using Owl Carousel and it worked fine.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes - could you show me an example of that working with my code? Perhaps I am too inexperienced or too dense to understand. Here is someone having a simuliar issue as me only they are using all AJAX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166868/ajax-pagination-for-instagram-api-tried-to-fix-bug

Comment: bro, you have to find a way out to call the api once user gets at the end of the page. After calling the api, just get the each 35 images embaded right after the images u got before. It will be a tricky challenge. It will take sometime and some brain storming to make something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the the api to work with client_id rather than access_token. You can change it back it will have no effect.

Demo: https://tjay.co/l/instagrampagination

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
function jsongram($next = null)
{
  $userid = "xxx";
  $accessToken = "xxx";
  $url = ("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?client_id={$accessToken}");

  if ( !empty($next) ) {
    $url.= '&max_id=' . $next;
  }

  // Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
  $cache = './' . sha1($url) . '.json';

  // unlink($cache); // Clear the cache file if needed

  // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
  if (file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60 * 60) {
      $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
  } else {
    $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    file_put_contents($cache, json_encode($jsonData));
  }

  return $jsonData;
}

function instaFormat($jsonData)
{
  $data_array = array();
  $response = array();

  foreach($jsonData->data as $data) {
    if ( !empty($data->caption->text) && stripos($data->caption->text, 'egypt') !== false ) { 
        $data_array[] = $data;
        $data = (str_split($data->caption->text));
        $data = (array_filter($data));
      }
  }

  $response['next'] = $jsonData->pagination->next_max_id;

  foreach($data_array as $data) {
      $igimglow = $data->images->low_resolution->url;
      // $igimgstd = $data->images->standard_resolution->url;
      // $igimgthumb = $data->images->thumbnail->url;
      // $igcaption = str_replace('#', '', (preg_replace('/(?:#[\w-]+\s*)+$/', '', $data->caption->text)));
      // $igtime = date("F j, Y", $data->caption->created_time);
      // $iglikes = $data->likes->count;
      // $igcomments = $data->comments->count;
      // $iglong = $data->location->longitude;
      // $iglat = $data->location->latitude;
      // $igusername = $data->user->username;
      // $igfullname = $data->user->full_name;
      // $iglink = $data->link;
      // $igfilter = $data->filter;
      // $igtags = implode(',', $data->tags);

      $response['data'][] = '<img src="'.$igimglow.'">';
  }

  return $response;
}

if ( isset($_POST['next']) ) {
  echo json_encode(instaFormat(jsongram($_POST['next'])));
  die();
}
```

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div data-pictures></div>

    <div><button type="button" data-get-next>Next</button></div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).on('get-feed', function(e, next_id) {

          var data = {
            next: next_id
          };

          $.post('ajax.php', data, function(response) {
            var container = $('[data-pictures]');
            response = $.parseJSON(response);

            container.html('');
            $('[data-get-next]').attr('data-get-next', response.next);

            $.each(response.data, function(i, val) {
              $(val).appendTo(container);
            });
          });
        });

        $('[data-get-next]').click(function() {
          var next_id = $(this).attr('data-get-next');
          $.event.trigger('get-feed', next_id);
        });

        $.event.trigger('get-feed', 0);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65067/discussion-on-answer-by-sixlive-load-more-instead-of-going-to-next-page-using-pa).

Comment: Can you show the actual guts of your solution in your answer itself please?

Comment: @sixlive - you around?